# How to retrieve number of likes from Facebook Like Button code

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, button, facebook-like

I need to check with PHP how many likes is showing in Facebook Like Button.

For some reasons I can't just perform a FQL query to get number of likes. I have to operate on a FB Like Button html/js code.

Example:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<fb:like href="http://www.example.com" send="false" width="450" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

I really don't want to install and use some JS interpreter to retrive Likes value. Is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: If you're trying to scrape the number of likes from a Facebook button on your site, you can't. That number lives in an iframe, so XSS security will apply. Getting the like count as a number is trivial using the API, but if you can't, it sounds like you're doing something that violates the Facebook TOS.

Comment: You are wrong. I can - every browser does that and there is nothing wrong about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the number of likes using FQL. For example, I created this like button using the [Like Button plugin creator tool](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/):

```
<fb:like href="http://plooza.com" send="false" width="450" show_faces="true"></fb:like>
```

Then I can get the number of likes using FQL, using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) as a quick test:

```
SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count, commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="plooza.com"
```

The output was:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "url": "plooza.com", 
      "normalized_url": "http://www.plooza.com/", 
      "share_count": 0, 
      "like_count": 2, 
      "comment_count": 0, 
      "total_count": 2, 
      "commentsbox_count": 0, 
      "comments_fbid": "1015079258276xxxx", 
      "click_count": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: As I wrote, I cannot perform a FQL query.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood. I thought you wanted to do FQL over PHP (or GET) to get the likes count for a like button, and you didn't want to use js. If you can't use js or FQL, you may be able to use Graph API, Eg. https://graph.facebook.com/122054155397

Comment: I cannot use Graph API either.